# Images disappear on refresh in heroku-hosted rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, caching, heroku

Let me say first that I'm quite new and inexperienced with rails. Today I tried to update an image in a rails app hosted on Heroku. Anyway, this is the simple flow I followed as I did other times before:

1. Add updated image to the image folder
2. Precompile the assets rake assets:precompile
3. Add and commit all changes
4. Push to heroku

Until this point all seems fine: I open Chrome to check my app from my domain and it's all there as expected.

The problem is that if I refresh the page all the images disappear (like they have never been loaded). This does not happen locally.
If I do a ctrl+f5 it all comes back nicely, but I lose everything again on simple refresh.. and so on.

Has anyone experienced something similar? I understand this might be hard to answer as there is not much code to show. Let me know if I can give more details.

On a final note, it seems that all works normally on a friends machine (that is, refresh doesn't give this problem). I'm thinking something might be wrong with my Chrome settings here? I don't remember having changed anything recently though.

This is very weird and quite annoying some help/insights would be great.

UPDATE: This seems indeed really to happen locally on my machine at work. I checked from another couple of computers at home and the app is displayed fine (without any refreshing problem).

Comment: I would recommend you setup the assets pipeline as per the [heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline) and let Heroku compile the assets after you push. It greatly reduces the amount of noise in your GIT history and eliminates the common misstake where you forgot to compile the assets or check them in before pushing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will surely look into that though I'm not sure if that's related to the problem. By the way, I checked at home on two computers (and my cellphone as well), and it all looks good. It seems this problem only occurs locally on my machine at work. :/

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the **cookie** is **disabled** by your browser for the heroku website in particular?

I have just tested this issue with an image based website (https://unsplash.com/). When the cookie is disabled for that website, pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> clears all the images, while pressing <kbd>Ctrl-F5</kbd> brings those lost resources back as like as your case.

**Enabling cookie** resolves the issue in my case.

Comment: Thanks for the hint but that does not seem to be the problem. Cookies are allowed and if I refresh any page (such as your example) I don't lose anything. It seems to happen only on Chrome on my app page.